# How to connect Firebase and Paypal with Zapier?

Tags: paypal, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, zapier

I have created Trigger and Action on Zapier.com 
Trigger == Paypal
Action == Firebase

> I just want when paypal make successful payment Action should be fire
>   using Zapier

When i make Trigger(with Paypal) they providing me Web hook to connect with Paypal like `https://hooks.zapier.com/hooks/paypal/?cid=1638056` Which i need to place in setting for IPN in paypal and enable it... Which i did  and tested (showing successfully connected with Paypal)

When i test this ZAP is working or not By inserting above URL in Paypal (sandbox > web hook simulator) and select payment completed or some other events to fire and click on `send..` button, it shows me `Your response is in queue .....` and doesn't fire action made in ZAP.

Sorry if you don't understand this test but in short, i want to connect paypal with firebase work correctly by Zapier